# I am trying to automate deploying to dynamics CRM and i have questions

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

To start out with, I'm looking for a way to unregister all plugins and delete the workflows in a specific environment then import the customizations.

what is the easiest way to un register plugins?

I have been doing a lot of research on this, but I can not find any working examples, so any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest having a look at this article: [Register Plug-ins Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg309620.aspx#bkmk_registerprog).

In particular:

> The key entity types used to register plug-ins and images are:
>   PluginAssembly, PluginType, SdkMessageProcessingStep, and
>   SdkMessageProcessingStepImage. The key entity types used to register
>   custom workflow activities are PluginAssembly and PluginType. Use
>   these entities with the create, update, retrieve, and delete
>   operations. **For sample code showing the use of these classes, see
>   the Plug-in Registration tool source code.**

Now I don't actually know for certain where this source code is, it used to be in the SDK, but I've just had a quick snoop around the CRM 2011 SDK and couldn't find it. (Microsoft used to ship just the source and people had to build it, now it appears they may just ship the binary).

In any case I believe you should be able to find the source in one of these locations, you might just have to dig around for it a little bit.

- [CRM 2011 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004).
- [CRM 4 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38).
- A codeplex project which claims to register plugins programmatically. [Plugin Registration Console Application Tool for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011.](http://pluginregcrm2011.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/19717)
- Failing that you could use IL-Spy to decompile the Plugin Registration Tool included in the 2011 SDK.

Comment: There is a code rescued from CRM SDK 2011 and adopted to usage with `XrmToolBox` https://github.com/macacq/PluginRegistration/ it also could be used for reference

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your definition of *easiest way*, and the number of plugins you have to unregister, using the plugin registration tool is probably the safest bet.

Comment: is there a way to automate that?   currently we do use that tool, but i am hoping to be able to script it so we can just run a bat and have it handle the process

Comment: I've never done that from a script. Of course, it's doable, since PRT does just that. My guess would be that you could do something with the metadata or go unsupported and write directly to the DB (if on-premise). But it's actually very interesting. I'll give it a try tomorrow and see what I can find out.

Answer (score 0):

The developer toolkit extension for Visual Studio (available in the SDK) installs a custom MSBuild target file and assembly with the required tasks.  I don't have it installed on this machine but I think the target file is called `Microsoft.CrmDeveloperTools.targets`.  Search your Program Files (x86) folder for *.targets.

If you're comfortable with MSBuild you could have a poke around to see what you can reuse or extend as required.  It will also hook nicely back into VS or any automated build system you may be running.

Alternatively or in combination with the above, the source code for the Plugin Registration Tool is also included in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old now, but I would suggest taking a look at this open source library I have recently developed to solve this problem. You can find it here: http://dazinator.github.io/CrmUp/